# Rails console can't open due to "Please install the postgresql adapter" error, in newly created app that doesn't use postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, rails-console

I'm running Rails 3.2.11, but this seems to happen in 3.2.10 and 3.2.9 for me as well. Essentially, I do

```
rails new sample_app
rails console
```

And this spits out:

```
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `call'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `each'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `load_console'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `load_console'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:153:in `load_console'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My question is: I'm using the default generated Gemfile and not even using postgres. Why is Rails complaining at me and how can I fix it? Could it be something to do with my gemset or RubyGems? Here is the Gemfile for reference:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

This is my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Please verify that postgresql isn't being specified in config/database.yml - it should use your preferred database instead.

That said, the default for a new rails application should be sqlite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding - I updated my question with the file; it's all sqlite3, as it should be.

Comment: Can you push this up to github so I can take a look - I can't replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I *am* using postgres in development. The problem went away for me when I updated the pg gem.

```
# Gemfile
# gem "pg", "~> 0.15.0"   # old line
gem "pg", "~> 0.17.0"     # new line
```

And I updated the gem:

```
$> bundle update pg
```

I started up the rails console and everything worked again.